# BackgroundWorker with Dispatcher doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: c#, mvvm, backgroundworker, dispatcher, wpf-4.0

I am trying to update an `ObservableCollection` that is data bound to the UI. I know that to do this I need to use `Dispatcher` and `BeginvInvoke()`, and to make it so that the UI doesn't freeze up when I do so, using a BackgroundWorker is a good way to go about it. In any event, I have all this, compiled and running, but nothing happens. I need to update the UI every 2 minutes or so, so I am also using a `DispatcherTimer`

This works, because DispatcherTimer is part of Dispatcher, but freezes the UI:

```
DispatcherTimer dispTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispTimer.Tick += dispTimer_Tick;
dispTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 45);
dispTimer.Start();

private void dispTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PartialEmployees.Clear();          
}
```

So, using the BackgroundWorker I pieced together this:

```
DispatcherTimer dispTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispTimer.Tick += dispTimer_Tick;
dispTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 45);
dispTimer.Start();

private void dispTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.DoWork += DoWork;            
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();

}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{            
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action(()=> 
        {
            PartialEmployees.Clear();
        }));
}
```

But nothing happens to the UI. What am I missing/not doing correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. When you use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from the background thread, it is getting the background thread's Dispatcher, not the UI thread's Dispatcher.
2. From your description I gather that your `PartialEmployees.Clear()` method takes significant time to execute and you want to avoid locking the UI thread during the execution.  However, having a BackgroundWorker invoke `PartialEmployees.Clear()` on your UI thread will have the same effect as using the DispatcherTimer, so you need a different solution than the one you are going for.

If you only want to fix the Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher problem, just store the current Dispatcher in a local variable like this:

```
private void dispTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  var uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

  BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker(); 
  _worker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
    uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
      PartialEmployees.Clear();
    }));
  _worker.RunWorkerAsync(); 
}
```

This will cause your UI change to work but it will still lock up the UI during the change, exactly as if you had not used BackgroundWorker.  The reason for this is:

1. The DispatcherTimer fires, executing on the UI thread.  All it does (dispTimer_Tick) is start a BackgroundWorker and then exit.
2. The BackgroundWorker executes on its own therad.  All it does is schedule a Dispatcher callback and then exit.
3. The Dispatcher callback executes on the UI thread again.  It calls PartialEmployees.Clear() which takes a while, locking up your UI thread while it executes.

So your behavior is the same as if the DispatcherTimer callback had called PartialEmployees.Clear() directly:  In each case the time-consuming operation is executed on the UI thread.

The reason for the lockup is that any time you do a large piece of work on the UI thread you will get a momentary lockup while it runs.  The solution is to break your work into smaller portions and do them one at a time, either from a DispatcherTimer or a BackgroundWorker.  In your case, examine the code for `PartialEmployees.Clear()` to see if it can be done incrementally.

Comment: Ok.Maybe I'm confused. Isn't the purpose of BackgroundWorker to do the work in the background, so the UI doesn't freeze; then use Dispatcher to marshall the changes to the UI thread? I'm using EntityFramework, .Clear() is built in for Lists. I don't want to do work in the UI thread, I just want to "refresh" the lists that are bound to the UI. I'm thinking that maybe this isn't possible and I will just have to put in a progress bar so that the user knows something is happening and the application is not frozen.

Comment: In that case you probably will need to bind your UI to a collection that is not maintained by EntityFramework, and when the EntityFramework collection fires CollectionChanged, use Dispatcher.Invoke to make the corresponding change in your bound collection, so that the UI-bound collection is updated on the UI thread.  You are right about the purpose of BackgroundWorker, and in fact it will suit your purpose for the *loading* of data through EntityFramework.  And as long as you update your UI in small pieces, the UI will not freeze.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using the method `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from the back ground thread.  What you need is the `Dispatcher` instance for the UI thread.

```
_worker.DoWork += delegate { DoWork(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher); };

...
private void DoWork(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
  dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    PartialEmployees.Clear();
  });
}
```

Comment: You can also just do MainWindow.Dispatcher or App.Current.Dispatcher (assuming you're not doing anything tricky like running runloops on > 1 thread)

Comment: This did not work either, it seems to be doing the work but the UI does not change. I'm thinking that I'm not using the UI dispatcher, so its doing the work on a different thread and then the UI wouldn't ever know. I could not do MainWindow.Dispatcher because 'an object reference is required' ... not sure what this is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need the background work, as `BeginInvoke` on the `Dispatcher` runs on a Threadpool thread.

something like this should work, and is more succinct

```
DispatcherTimer dispTimer = new DispatcherTimer 
    {Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)};
dispTimer.Tick += (o,e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
    .BeginInvoke((Action)PartialEmployees.Clear);
dispTimer.Start();
```